# How to bind the ItemSource and SelectedItem with String in ComboBox?

Tags: c#, wpf

In XAML:

```
<ComboBox x:Uid="ComboBox_1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Companies}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Company}"/>
```

In ViewModel:

```
public ObservableCollection Companies { get; private set; }
public string Company{ get; private set; }
```

And I will add the single Company to Companies list in ViewModel constructor

But it doesn't work, and the whole XAML will crash.

Not sure why....

Can anybody tell me the reason, thanks in advance

Comment: What is the error message when crash and why private set ?

Comment: What is the type of items in `ObservableCollection<T>`?

Comment: Remove the private set in this line.. public string Company{ get; private set; }

Comment: Miyazaki, you want the view to update the property Company. But how can that happen if Company has a private setter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the default 'BindingMode Enumeration' for ComboBox is "TwoWay", it is good sign your Xaml crashes, as he lets you know (in his own way..): "Hey, I'm trying to bind the ViewModel to the Model, it a two way binding mode, but the view model says he's not willing to participate".

In other words, you VM properties most be public for your code to work. Dedicate a few minutes

If you want a one-way mode, only to get stuff from the view model to the view but not the other way around, you can do it:

In that case you can leave your View Model as is.